# Do the following conditions for a map imply the map is conformal?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f: A \to B$ is bijective and preserves angles and also suppose $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist are are continous. Does it follow that $f$ is analytic and conformal??

I think it is enough to show that $f$ is analytic and that $f'(z) \neq 0 $ for all $z \in A $. How can I use the hyphotesis that $f$ is angle preserving to show what I want ?

Comment: $f(z)=\overline{z}:{\Bbb D}\to{\Bbb D}$ is bijective, which ${\Bbb D}=\{|z|<1\}$ and $f_x$, $f_y$ exist and are continous. $f$ is preserves angles but is not analytic and conformal.

Comment: What is your definition of "preserves angles"?  What is your definition of "conformal"?

Comment: What the difference between "preserves angles" and "conformal"?

Comment: Sometimes "preserves angles" is used to mean isogonal, rather than conformal. That was the assumption I answered under, but I edited to include both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "preserves angles"

If you mean "preserves the size and orientation of angles" (i.e. conformal), then it does follow that the map is analytic and conformal. Conformal is obviously trivial, and although the proof of analyticity is not occurring to me right now, it's stated on [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConformalMapping.html)

If you mean "preserves the size of angles", then these conditions do not imply that the map is analytic and conformal. As noted in the comments, $f(z)=\overline{z}$ as a bijection of $\mathbb{D}$ is a counter-example. This is an important counter-example, as it is, in some essential sense, the only one. It is guaranteed for the map to either be conformal and analytic, or for $f(z)$ to be "analytic with respect to $\overline{z}$" instead of actually analytic and [isogonal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsogonalMapping.html).

Comment: The complex conjugate map doesn't preserve angles, it negates them!

Comment: You're right. The word I meant to use is isogonal